# Discord.js HTTP Request

Tags: http, discord.js, httpwebrequest

I am a new developer that barley knows discord.js
I am trying to send an request to https://rolimons.com
The request is going to be to add a player to a database
using this api
https://www.rolimons.com/playerapi/addplayer?playername=(playernamehere)
I am really not sure how to do it. I would appreciate it if someone would help me out.
Thanks

Comment: Question is to broad. StackOverflow is for specific questions on specific items that are beneficial to the group as a whole. There are other forums to lean the basics of discord.js

Answer (score 0):

You can use various packages to fetch data, like node-fetch, axios etc.

**node-fetch:** [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)

**axios**: [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)